# Will the Thread.currentThread() method always return the same object troughout the Runnable's lifetime?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been using Thread#currentThread() in my Runnable#run() method to get a reference to the currently executing thread. Since the Runnable can be running for a while with multiple similar copies in parallel in an Executor, will it always return the same Thread object or can that change over the course of the the lifetime of the Runnable?

So basically, will I run into issues when I run this kind of Runnable for a while?

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
  
  @Override
  public void run() {
     Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
     
     while(!current.isInterrupted()) {
        try {
          // some processing that can take a while...
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
          // some cleanup
          current.interrupt();
        }
     }

     // goodbye
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question. As long as code is executed within the same thread, the expression `Thread.currentThread()` will evaluate to the same object, which represents that thread.

But this has nothing to do with the “`Runnable`’s lifetime”. The `Runnable`, or more precisely the instance of the class implementing runnable, is an ordinary object that can be used independently of threads. Most notably, multiple threads may execute the `run()` method of the same object:

```java
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println(current);
    }
}

MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();

new Thread(r).start();
new Thread(r).start();
new Thread(r).start();
```

```
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
```

This, however doesn’t imply that it was wrong to assume to get the same `Thread` instance for a particular execution.

To built on your example code:

```java
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
        while(!current.isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                current.interrupt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(current+" has been interrupted, exiting");
    }
}

MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();

Thread[] threads = { new Thread(r), new Thread(r), new Thread(r) };

for(Thread t: threads) t.start();
for(Thread t: threads) try {
    Thread.sleep(400);
    System.out.println("going to interrupt "+t);
    t.interrupt();
    t.join();
}
catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    throw new AssertionError(ex);
}
```

will correctly print:

```
going to interrupt Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] has been interrupted, exiting
going to interrupt Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
Thread[Thread-1,5,main] has been interrupted, exiting
going to interrupt Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
Thread[Thread-2,5,main] has been interrupted, exiting
```

So `Thread.currentThread()` will return the same object throughout the *threads* lifetime (when being called from that thread), not the runnable`s lifetime, but that’s precisely what you want. You could also use

```java
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" has been interrupted, exiting");
    }
}
```

to the same effect. But keep in mind that the first example works because the thread has been stored in a *local variable*. If you are going to store the thread into a field of the object, you have to ensure that the object is not used by multiple threads concurrently (as you always have to take care when using shared mutable state by multiple threads).

Answer (score 0):

Each `Thread` has its own ID and you can call method [getId()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId--) to obtain it. Then you can determine if it is the same `Thread`.

From the *javadoc* of the method `getId()`

> Returns the identifier of this Thread. The thread ID is a positive long number generated when this thread was created. The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime. When a thread is terminated, this thread ID may be reused.

Answer (score -1):

> Will the Thread.currentThread() method always return the same object troughout the Runnable's lifetime?

Yes, `Thread.currentThread()` will return the same reference anytime you invoke it in a particular thread; however not *throughout the Runnable's lifetime*, but rather throughout the lifetime of the *current* thread.

`Runnable` type exists independent from the `Thread`, and you can use it without the latter. If you, for example, store the `Runnable` instance reference in some variable, and you will pass the same instance to the `Thread`, exiting the runner thread will not cause the deallocation of that instance of the `Runnable`.

You should note, that once the *thread* kicks off with [`.start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#start())(after which, JVM internally calls `.run()`), it is illegal to restart the thread after it completes execution. Generally, it is never legal to start the same thread more than once.

So, every time you call [`Thread.currentThread()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread()), you will obtain the reference to the *currently executing thread* object (reference to the *thread*, in which, this method is invoked).

Comment: Your last clarification has me confused: it will return the currently executing thread at the start of run() and it will return the SAME Thread object if I call it x hours later?

Comment: Which part of my answer has exactly confused you? Yes, if you have `Thread.currentThread()` invocation in thread `X`, you will be getting the same reference (to the current thread) anytime you invoke `Thread.currentThread()`, as long as that thread is living.

Comment: Ah yes, you edited your response, it is now much clearer, thank you!

I was worried that Java (or one of its libraries) has some way of saving the state of the Runnable making it able to move across threads mid-execution (or more likely, mid-sleep).

Comment: Think of it this way: You always have your code (`Thread.currentThread()`) in some, currently executing thread, right? right. So, once that thread is started, anytime you invoke `Thread.currentThread()`, you will receive same object reference, **as long as** that thread is alive.

Comment: I was also trying to avoid having to use Thread.currentThread() all the time ;)

Comment: Careful, @Wim.  Although Java provides an enduring 1:1 association between `Thread` objects and threads of execution, and you cannot (and Java does not) assign a different `Runnable` to an existing `Thread` object or swap a `Runnable` to a new `Thread`, you *can*, yourself, initialize multiple `Thread`s with the same `Runnable` and run those `Thread`s concurrently.  But Java will not do that behind your back.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yet, he will still create two distinct threads, with different IDs, with this approach.

Comment: Yes, @GiorgiTsiklauri, that is the point.  It follows that multiple invocations of `Thread.currentThread()` by the same `Runnable` object can return different `Thread` objects.  The OP must judge whether their `Runnable` usage is susceptible to that; it is not safe to assume *a priori* that it cannot ever happen.

Comment: Sure, OP should be aware that if one passes the same *runnable* to x (x>1) number of Threads, one might get the different print result when doing `Thread.currentThread()`, yet, that is not due to the same thread giving back the different IDs, but rather because the method is invoked within the different threads. If I get your point correctly. :)

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri will definitely accept an answer but I would like to give it a bit more time, maybe someone comes along with a better one! (doubt it though)

@JohnBollinger as I am trying to avoid having the same `Runnable` object being run in multiple threads over it's lifetime, I am definitely also making sure that I don't have the same `Runnable` being executed by multiple threads, thanks for the additional comments! :)

Comment: @Wim there is nothing wrong with using the same `Runnable` with multiple threads. This depends on what the runnable does. Also, the other way round, the use of a `Runnable` doesn’t have to imply the creation of a new thread. Calling `ifPresentOrElse(…, runnable)` on an `Optional` will directly execute the runnable’s `run()` method when the optional is empty. No additional threads involved. And you may re-use the runnable afterwards. When using stateless lambda expressions, this re-use may happen automatically.